# slope and Intercept point in graph

Tags: python

I have a very simple data of

```
x=[3,8,12,22,36,25,46,52]
y=[3,9,11,25,36,27,48,55]
pylab.plot(x,y)
```

how can I find the slope and the intercept of this graph

Answer (score 1):

use `scipy.stats.linregress`  ref [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

X = np.array([3,8,12,22,36,25,46,52])
Y = np.array([3,9,11,25,36,27,48,55])

slope, intercept , r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X,Y)

print(slope,intercept)
```

using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([3,8,12,22,36,25,46,52])
Y = np.array([3,9,11,25,36,27,48,55])

slope, intercept = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)

print(slope,intercept)
```

o/p:

```
1.046875 0.0546875
```

Comment: it says that stats is not defined. can you tell me the exact code please

Comment: please check my answer with numpy

Comment: @p.kumar, Updated my answer